# Filter android monitor logs by package name

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Is it possible, like with the old monitor, to filter logs from the new android monitor by package name without having an application launched by Android Studio ?

I tried to create logcat filter configuration, but it doesn't work if I didn't launch an application with Android Studio.

Comment: You only can log the application `if I didn't launch an application with Android Studio.` when you have `android:debuggable="true"` in its manifest on release build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly view logcat with the help of `adb`.
Use command like

```
adb logcat | grep <your_package_name>
```

as per @TruongHieu mentioned in comment, flag is `true`.

for more [info](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html).

Comment: I'm aware with the limitation of the flag true in the manifest. It is that with the old monitor, we could easily filter the logs by adding a filter on package name. With the new, the filter don't seem to work. I don't know why they made this half-baked android-logcat the default.